# Replacing text and duplicates

Tags: regex, linux, replace

I have a log file with lines filled with things like this:

```
/home/Users/b/biaxib/is-clarithromycin-effective-against-strep.html
/home/Users/b/hihi/low-cost-biaxin-free-shipping.html
/home/Users/b/hoho/no-script-biaxin-fast-delivery.html
/home/Users/b/ihatespam/no-script-low-cost-biaxin.html
```

I want to extract only the username portion, and then remove duplicates, so that I am only left with this:

```
biaxib 
hihi 
hoho
ihatespam
```

The ruleset is:

- Extract the text between "/home/Users/" and "/....." at the end
- Remove duplicate lines after the above rule is applied
- Do this inside Linux

Can someone help me with how to create such a script, or statement to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that username always appears at 4th component of path:

```
$ cat test.txt
/home/Users/b/biaxib/is-clarithromycin-effective-against-strep.html
/home/Users/b/hihi/low-cost-biaxin-free-shipping.html
/home/Users/b/hoho/no-script-biaxin-fast-delivery.html
/home/Users/b/ihatespam/no-script-low-cost-biaxin.

$ cat test.txt | cut -d/ -f 5 | sort | uniq
biaxib
hihi
hoho
ihatespam
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /path/to/your/log/file.txt | python3 -c '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
import sys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    print( line.split("/")[5] )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
' | sort | uniq
```

More conciseness probably achievable in perl or with other builtin tools (see other answer), but I personally shy away from the standard linux text manipulation tools (edit: `cut` is a useful one though).